# Find n-th derivative of the function, display it and then evaluate it at a point of choice

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, expression-manipulation

What would be the correct syntax to find the order derivative "$n$" in MMA, and to be able to evaluate it in a certain point.

We ask for an example ;

Find the order derivative 2 and evaluate it at point $x=1.5$

```
f[x_]:=(1-x^2)Cos[x^2] +2x Sin[x^3]
```

MMA should show this

```
f'[x]=-2 x Cos[x^2] + 6 x^3 Cos[x^3] - 2 x (1 - x^2) Sin[x^2] + 2 Sin[x^3]
```

*f'[1.5]=-107809*

Find the order derivative n and evaluate it at point $x=1.5$
How is this implemented?

Comment: See the documentation of `D`. You can use `ReplaceAll` (a.k.a. `/.`) for evaluation at a specific point. For example `D[f[x],{x,2}] /. x -> 1.5`.

Comment: @Henrik Shumacher;thanks for answering i saw the documentation but i can't find the way to represent the umpteenth derivative, my english is not very good

Comment: Have you tried to evaluate `?D` and to read the second line?

Comment: @ Henrik Schumache,sorry ohhh, I didn't know that simple shortcut

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher,how much I try the derivative of order n leaves a salad of functions ,what happens there?

Comment: Well, I did not expect that you want the $n$-th derivative for _symbolic_ $n$. In general, the expressions for that can become quite complicated and what you see is _Mathematica_'s way to deal with it. Not that I would understand what's going on...

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher In the initial question I asked for the umpteenth derivative, the order 2 derivative was only an example and that problem I saw on the net and it was expected that whoever answered it, would find the order n derivative, I asked wolframalpha and he gave me a shorter result and tried to obtain the same with MMA without results.

Answer (score 1):

Recommend to use `Derivative`.

We can compare with the three approach. Here we calculate the seconder order derivative.

```
f[x_] := (1 - x^2) Cos[x^2] + 2 x*Sin[x^3];
f''[x] /. x -> 1.5
D[f[x], {x, 2}] /. x -> 1.5
Derivative[2][f][1.5]
```

Comment: thanks for the indication

Comment: thanks for the indication but I look for an expression for the derivative of order n ,not evaluated at any point